# Absolute position from relative

Tags: python, list

Provided that I have a Python list of strings of words, how do I get absolute position of a given word in the whole list, as opposed to relative position within the string?

```
l = ['0word0 0word1 0word2', '1word0 1word1 1word2', '2word0 2word1']
rel_0word2 = l[0].split().index('1word2') # equals 2
abs_0word2 = ??? # equals 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't make variables called `l`. It looks too close to a `1`.

Comment: Better yet don't make one or two letter variables unless the context calls for it (for example mathematical formulas). It makes readability suffer.

Comment: I would argue that at least in this case it can be inferred from context (since assignment to literal isn't valid in Python and is a non sequitur overall), but point taken in general, thx for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure on what you mean on absolute position, please find below my sample:

```
l = ['0word0 0word1 0word2', '1word0 1word1 1word2', '2word0 2word1']

print [x for w in l for x in w.split()].index('1word2')
```

Or:

```
def get_abs_pos(lVals, word):
    return [i for i,x in enumerate([x for w in l for x in w.split()]) if x == word]
```

And the shortest one:

```
' '.join(l).split().index('1word2')
```

Comment: That's not it. Perhaps I have explained it awkwardly or perhaps it's smth else, but I need the index of the given word, counting from the beginning of the list and ignoring string boundaries (e.g. '1word2' in the above list has relative position 2 but absolute 5, which is what I need).

Comment: All my samples returns 5 for '1word2'

Comment: There's no reason to use `extend` here. There's no question that especially for easy lists like this, generators are always better.

Comment: @machine - thank you - sure, edited my samples to not be so weird

Comment: I personally think your last solution `' '.join(l).split().index('1word2')`  is the cutest, but I wonder how it would do in terms of performance. Earned my upvote though! +1 for stealing public knowledge with no remorse and claiming it as your own! :)

Comment: I have stolen? What do you mean on this? I thought that my last one solution was not mentioned in other answers?

Comment: @Artsiom: Haha no I just meant by taking my approach to the other problem and incorporating it into your own solution. I didn't mean it in a bad way, I think that all knowledge should be publically shared and it doesn't matter who gets credit in the end. As long as the best answer eventually sees the spotlight, and the best answer is definitely yours. That's why you got my upvote! No hard feelings, I hope you didn't take my comment the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is nest your generators right:

```
>>> sentences = ['0word0 0word1 0word2', '1word0 1word1 1word2', '2word0 2word1']
>>> all_words = [w for words in sentences for w in words.split()]
>>> all_words
['0word0', '0word1', '0word2', '1word0', '1word1', '1word2', '2word0', '2word1']
>>> all_words.index('1word1')
4
```

Or if you want to do it with iterators (maybe if you're working with lots of long strings or something), you can try playing around with the `chain` function (my new personal fav).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following:

```
def GetWordPosition(lst, word):
    if not word in lst:
        return -1

    index = lst.index(word)
    position = 0
    for i in xrange(index):
        position += len(lst[i])

    return position
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative answer that is based on an iterative solution:

```
def find_in_sentences(find_me, sentences):
    i = 0
    for sentence in sentences:
        words = sentences.split()
        if find_me in words:
            return words.index(find_me) + i
        else:
            i += len(words)
    return False
```

Not quite as one-liner-spiffy as the generator, but it does it all without needing to construct a big long list.

Answer (score -1):

Use `string.find`, as can be viewed in the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find).

```
l = ['0word0 0word1 0word2', '1word0 1word1 1word2', '2word0 2word1']
index = l[0].find('0word2')
```

Comment: Edited above. What I need, is the absolute position of the word from the beginning of the list; `fn('1word2') -> 5`.